# I have enabled filestream, but when I try to create database i get the error 5591 (filestream disabled)

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I am using SQL Server 2016 express, I went to manager configuration and in properties of the server, I check the three checks in the filestream tab.

Later, in management studio, in the properties of the server, I ensure that filestream is enabled in full access mode.

But when I have to restore a database that use filestream, I get the error 5591, that filestream is not enabled.

Also I executed this script:

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
RECONFIGURE
```

I am using windows 10 as OS.

Thanks.

Comment: did you restart sql server after configuring file stream

Comment: yes, I restarted, and also I have tried to unistall sql server and reinstall all. But the problem is not solved.

Comment: What does log says,can you paste exact error msg